# VSTS - Releases based on branches - environment-deployment condition gone?

Tags: git, build, azure-devops, release-management

Currently vsts (online) has changed up it release designer. And have "semi" broken some of my build/releases.

First of this is/was my setup.

I have 3 environments:

- Dev
- Test
- Prod

I am using git as source-control in visualstudio.com.

I have set up continuously build on 1 build-definition that trigger on branches:

- development
- release/*
- master

I have then set up a continuously release (1 release definition) from build (old-editor), where I have defined 3 environments (dev, test, prod) where on each I have defined deployment-condition:

- Dev - only builds from commits in develop branch
- Test - only builds from commits in release branches
- Prod - only builds from commits in master branch

This worked fine until the new release-designer rolled out.

Now the deployment-condition option on environment, where you can define specific branches, is gone. It "seems" to be replaced by the "Continuous deployment trigger" on the artifact.
Also my releases did not "release" after the update, but after I defined the branches on "Continuous deployment trigger" on artifact, it worked as expected again.

So for the time being it is working as expected (as long I can access old editor), but am worried that if/when the old editor disappear I can't configure as I want it to.

Only way to "mimic" this behavior in the new editor, I think, is to have have 3 release definition, one for each branch (on artifact trigger).

But that's a lot of release definitions, and the release overview UI would get real messy.

Any insight or tips?

I think what I am asking here is :)

- Is deployment-condition on environments in a release-def deprecated?
- Is there a better way to handle it in the new editor?

Cheers.

Comment: FYI: The new editor just added this feature :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some features aren't expressed in the new editor yet. You can fall back to the old editor by clicking *Edit (old editor)* link.

Comment: Ok (what I am doing now), hopefully they will remember to include that feature in the new editor.